# Distribute VM and force new mac address

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, nic

I wish to distribute a VMWare VM for users (who are technically challenged and unable to install a complex product).  Users may run several instances of the VM in their environment, so it's essential that each VM have NIC's with unique MAC addresses.

Is there a way to distribute the VM in such a way that on first boot if forces new MAC addresses onto the NIC's?

If users just add the VM to their inventory and select 'moved' instead of 'copied' then they get the same MAC's (I believe).

I'm using VMWare WOrkstation 12 in case that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical "correct" way to distribute VM images for VMware vSphere is to distribute .ova files created using ovftool, and then use the vSphere GUI to install the .ova file. This automatically distributes a "copied" version of the virtual machine that has a different MAC address when deployed. However, there is a way to do the job if you're going to instead distribute a zipped up VMware Workstation directory. What you need to do is, immediately before you zip up the directory, is first copy the .vmx file someplace else. Then edit the vmx file and look for a line that looks like

```
ethernet0.generatedAddress = "00:0c:29:28:70:9d"
```

Remove that line from the vmx file.

Then zip it up and distribute it. That should give you copy of the virtual machine that does not have a built in MAC address and that should generate a new MAC address upon deployment. (This is assuming a VM with a single Ethernet interface). Then copy the original .vmx file back into place.

Note that for certain operating systems, such as Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6, there are udev rules that tie a specific Ethernet interface to a specific MAC address. These must be removed to allow eth0 to come up after the deployment. If your operating system is one of those, that is a separate question.

Comment: I see 'export to ovf' in VMWare workstation.  Will an OVF created a "copied" version like ova (from vSphere)?

Comment: Yes, change the filename to "SomethingSomething.ova" when it puts up the file dialog and it will produce a single-file compressed OVA archive rather than a multi-file OVF directory.